# nodeos compilation and missing libsoci_core.so.4.0 library

Tags: nodeos, compilation

compiled and installed latest release of soci lib.
set $PATH to include compiled libraries.
compiled 1.1 release with sql plugin
now they i try to run nodeos with sql plugin enabled i get this error:

/usr/local/eosio/bin/nodeos: error while loading shared libraries: libsoci_core.so.4.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

how to set the path where nodeos will look for this libs? or do i make something really wrong?

and by the way - i have found the error in sql plugin code which prevents it from compilation. should i make a PR?

Comment: sql plugin is not available now

Comment: What do you mean? It is in main EOSIO repo.